# Procedure para deletar e logo em seguida inserir dados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alguém poderia me orientar sobre como construir uma procedure para deletar dados de uma tabela(já criada com SELECT INTO), todo dia tal hora e logo seguida preenchê-la novamente. Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos.

Comment: Isso você vai precisar fazer com um JOB, que execute diariamente chamando sua proc.

Comment: Primeiramente: Deletar porque e preencher com o que? Na minha opinião está muita vaga sua pergunta.

Comment: André, desculpe se não foi de fácil entendimento para você minha pergunta. A questão é, criei uma consulta muito grande e demora um pouco para "rodar", então joguei os dados dela para uma tabela usando SELECT INTO, só que todos os dias preciso que essa consulta rode novamente afim de verificar se houve alguma mudança, então pensei em criar uma procedure para deletar os dados dessa nova tabela e realizar um insert novamente depois que a consulta "gigante" rodar.

Comment: Ok, no caso, você pode criar um JOB no SQL Server ou pelo agendador de tarefas do windows para rodar sua rotina no horário determinado. Segue um exemplo de proc simples que pode te dar uma luz: CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Limpa_Insere
AS
BEGIN
 TRUNCATE TABLE teste
 INSERT INTO teste VALUES('TESTE','TESTE')
END

Comment: Show André, já serviu sim como uma luz, agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Marcilio primeiramente qualquer duvida que tenha poste seu exemplo para podermos analisar.

Vamos la

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma

Poderá criar uma tabela temporaria simples com # ou global com #

Independente do que você colocou no seu select você ira fazer desta forma

```
Drop Table #Select_muito_grande
"Inserir as informações do seu select"
Into #Select_muito_grande
FROM "o restante das informações da sua consulta
```

OBS: não se esqueça de utilizar WITH (NOLOCK) para otimizar o processo.